# Error on adding a number into a table

Tags: sql, python-2.7, postgresql

i want to get the date of this website and i can get it but it returns an error adding to the column. 
Print: http://prntscr.com/fsav5h

Code:

```
page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.meetup.com/find/events/career-business/?allMeetups=false&radius=50&userFreeform=London&mcId=c1012717&change=yes')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find('div', class_='unit size5of7 ')

A = []

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='meetup' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='root'")
except:
    print 'Unable to connect to the database.'

cur = conn.cursor()

for event in events.findAll('ul', class_="searchResults resetList clearfix"):
    date = event.findAll('li', class_="date-indicator")
    if len(date) != 0:
        A.append(date[0].find(text = True))
        cur.execute("""UPDATE events SET event_date = %s WHERE event_date = '' """ % tuple(A) )
        conn.commit()
        del A[:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
cur.execute("""UPDATE events SET event_date = '%s' WHERE event_date = '' """, (tuple(A)))
```

Comment: It continues to happen :c

Comment: verify that the date format is accepted in Postgres. Try to update directely in Postgres.

Comment: Postgres accepts it. I removed also the WHERE event_date = ' ' because it was returning 0 rows affected.

Comment: if you add two quotes to %s  -->  '%s'  ?

Comment: Do you know how to remove whitespace? I tried .strip() but it's not working :c

Comment: yourString.replace(" ", "") to remove  all spaces

Comment: I don't want to remove all the spaces.. I want to remove the whitespaces like this: "
3


Rock Climbers

going

"

Comment: yourString = ''.join(yourString.split()) and this ?